# Spring boot: IS IT BEST practice to call many repositories in one service or use one query in one repository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

i have a service where i need to update an entity A but i need to do a verification on all childrens of this entity so i need to call others repositories to retrieve the children because my entities are not related by foreign key and i can't use JPA relationship

i have entity A with  id and code , entity B with id and codeB  and entity C with id and codeC. entityA.code == entityB.codeB , entityB.code == entityC.codeC so i need to retrieve all the children of entity A with theses conditions  so i have to solutions:

--first solution :
in the service , i can inject repository B and repository C and I can retrieve  all data of entity B and entity C and add them into collection but i does not respect the SRP (single responsability principe) because the service does many things instead of juste calling the repository A and retrieve children

---second solution

create query in repository A to find all children by using the conditions i have mentioned before but i find this not readable in the repository because it make a big query

thank you in advance

i try to retrieve all children of an entity A in one service by injecting many repositories of entity B and entity C but i dont't know if it is good solution, maye, it is better to do this in one query in repository A